Why is my Blazor Web App throwing a SocketException when authenticating with OpenIddict when deployed to Azure App Service?
I have a Blazor Web App running with Interactive Server Render Mode, and an ID Provider built using OpenIddict. The Blazor App is configured to use the Microsoft OpenIdConnectHandler, essentially following this guide: https://damienbod.com/2024/04/15/implement-a-secure-blazor-web-application-using-openid-connect-and-security-headers/
When I run the two apps locally everything works as expected.
However when I deploy them into Azure, I am redirected to the Login page (on the IDP) successfully, but then on successful authentication I end up in an infinite loop between /signin-oidc on the Blazor app, and the authorize endpoint on the IDP.
When I look at the logs produced, this seems to be the only exception, even though it looks like OpenIddict has successfully handled the token request:
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler EventId: 17 SpanId: d04c97209a4248cf TraceId: f1015c14eb411718858a680b84fb7145 ParentId: 0000000000000000 RequestId: 80000052-0001-e700-b63f-84710c7967bb RequestPath: /signin-oidc Exception occurred while processing message. Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
  ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Int32>.GetResult(Int16 token)
    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 estimatedSize)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.Metrics.MetricsHandler.SendAsyncWithMetrics(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync() 

However, now I am not sure if this is the actual error or whether this just happens when I cancel the request.
I have tried cloning this repo https://github.com/damienbod/BlazorServerOidc and changing the config to use my IDP and then deploying that into Azure, and this works as expected.
I then add to this all of my pages and components, leaving the configuration the same, but I get the same problem.
Given that a) I have a number of other apps that work (SPA's running React) b) it works locally with Blazor c) my "template" unmodified Blazor app works - why would I be getting this problem?

Since the issue only occurred in Azure web app and the blazor server app worked well locally all the time, I'm afraid there's something wrong within the azure web app instance which treate the valid authentication result as invalid so that the app redirect back to sign in page. But since the authentication had done successfully, so that the identity platform redirect back to blazor app again and cause an infinite loop. My assumption is that we could try to create a new Azure web app instance/app service and publish your app to test again.

@user27687530 Check if your IDP is allowing CORS for the Azure App Service.

Thanks both - in fact I do have CORS allowed on the IDP, and it still doesn't work. I have since found that when I remove this line from the Blazor server Program.cs it works (although I need it for other things to work) builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

@user27687530 - Is your issue resolved?

I found that AddIdentity adds a bunch of cookies and auth schemas to the app, and I think this was interfering with what I was trying to do. However, since I still needed some of the services that are added by Identity, I changed it to AddIdentityCore and configured the EF Core stores, etc. and it now works.
